# Understanding the 2N2222 transistor, Where is this voltage coming from

Tags: transistors, npn, proteus

I was using Proteus to simulate NPN transistor then I saw this [image]
Both Switches are open. Why I see 3.12 Volts

Comment: is the simulation running? ... what happens if you place a 100 meg ohm resistor across the voltmeter?

Comment: Voltmeters have an ideally infinite series resistance, therefore your emitter is basically floating, also don't apply a voltage source directly to the BE junction of a transistor without a resistor.

Comment: Your switches are open. Got it. I think the reason is probably related to a simulator parameter called ***gmin***. Look it up. It's applied to non-linear devices (which a BJT is) and is applied differently with different Spice programs. So you won't even get the same simulation from any two of them. But it could also be further confounded (made more difficult to tease out, completely) due to the impedance your simulator assigns to an open switch, too. So that's another thing to investigate.

Comment: What happens if you attach the ground symbol to the (-) of the supplies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same result.

[image]

Ammeters go in series.  Voltmeters in parallel.  If you check properties of voltmeter, it is a 100M\$\Omega\$ in series with emitter.  It is a simulation, not reality.  The program has to come up with a number and 3.12V is it.

[image]

Make the following changes and your circuit will work.

You do not need two switches.  Essential, as you have it wired, the 2N2222 is functioning as a switch.  You need resistors on base and collector.  I chose at random.  And voltmeters go in parallel.  Ammeters must be changed to mAmmeters.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The voltmeter is high-impedance, so the emitter of the transistor is not connected to ground. You should instead connect the emitter to the + terminal of the ammeter that you currently have in series with the voltmeter. That will ensure that the emitter node is shorted to the voltage source negative (ground).

As for why you measure 3.12 volts - in the configuration drawn, all three terminals of the transistor are disconnected when the switches are open. So, the voltage is arbitrary - maybe the simulator solved for that in an initial condition search, or maybe it's a value left on an internal capacitance inside the transistor if you've been toggling the switches while the sim is running.

Note that in the configuration drawn, your base voltage will be much higher than the knee voltage of the base-emitter junction (around 0.65 V at room temperature), so all that'll happen is you'll sink a whole bunch of current from the base to emitter while also saturating the transistor. You probably want to either add a series resistance to limit the base current, feed the base from a current source, or *slowly* creep the voltage up from zero until you hit the knee (Vbe vs base current is exponential when fed from a voltage source, just like any diode).